# Setting up a staging environment on heroku for spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, spree, environment

I was trying to create a staging environment for my spree application that is hosted on heroku. At first everything went fine using heroku fork and such.. I got a nice copy of my production environment. Then I copied the production.rb and renamed it to staging.rb. After that I've changed the environment variables on my  heroku staging app to "staging", for RAILS_ENV and RAKE_ENV. Then I also created an entry for "staging" on my database.yml containing the same information like it has for "production". My last step was to make sure that every gem is also available for staging.

After pushing these changes the staging environment crashed. And I don't understand. Everything should be the same like on production..

Here is my log.

```
2015-09-01T15:20:04.810652+00:00 app[web.1]: Environment: staging
2015-09-01T15:20:07.093698+00:00 app[web.1]: App 111 stdout:
2015-09-01T15:20:12.822511+00:00 app[web.1]: App 111 stdout:   Spree::Preference Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "spree_preferences".* FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE "spree_preferences"."key" = $1  ORDER BY "spree_preferences"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["key", "spree/app_configuration/logo"]]
2015-09-01T15:20:12.882026+00:00 app[web.1]: App 111 stdout:    (0.5ms)  COMMIT
2015-09-01T15:20:12.882005+00:00 app[web.1]: App 111 stdout:   Spree::Preference Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE ("spree_preferences"."key" = 'spree/app_configuration/logo' AND "spree_preferences"."id" != 7) LIMIT 1
2015-09-01T15:20:12.882027+00:00 app[web.1]: App 111 stdout:   Spree::Preference Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "spree_preferences".* FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE "spree_preferences"."key" = $1  ORDER BY "spree_preferences"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["key", "spree/print_invoice_setting/storage_path"]]
2015-09-01T15:20:12.882010+00:00 app[web.1]: App 111 stdout:    (0.5ms)  COMMIT
2015-09-01T15:20:12.882029+00:00 app[web.1]: App 111 stdout:    (0.5ms)  BEGIN
2015-09-01T15:20:12.882017+00:00 app[web.1]: App 111 stdout:   Spree::Preference Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "spree_preferences".* FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE "spree_preferences"."key" = $1  ORDER BY "spree_preferences"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["key", "spree/app_configuration/allow_guest_checkout"]]
2015-09-01T15:20:12.882030+00:00 app[web.1]: App 111 stdout:   Spree::Preference Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE ("spree_preferences"."key" = 'spree/print_invoice_setting/storage_path' AND "spree_preferences"."id" != 22) LIMIT 1
2015-09-01T15:20:12.882019+00:00 app[web.1]: App 111 stdout:    (0.5ms)  BEGIN
2015-09-01T15:20:12.882031+00:00 app[web.1]: App 111 stdout:    (0.5ms)  COMMIT
2015-09-01T15:20:12.882020+00:00 app[web.1]: App 111 stdout:   Spree::Preference Exists (4.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE ("spree_preferences"."key" = 'spree/app_configuration/allow_guest_checkout' AND "spree_preferences"."id" != 19) LIMIT 1
2015-09-01T15:20:12.882021+00:00 app[web.1]: App 111 stdout:    (0.5ms)  COMMIT
2015-09-01T15:20:12.882024+00:00 app[web.1]: App 111 stdout:    (0.5ms)  BEGIN
2015-09-01T15:20:12.882022+00:00 app[web.1]: App 111 stdout:   Spree::Preference Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "spree_preferences".* FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE "spree_preferences"."key" = $1  ORDER BY "spree_preferences"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["key", "spree/print_invoice_setting/store_pdf"]]
2015-09-01T15:20:12.882025+00:00 app[web.1]: App 111 stdout:   Spree::Preference Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE ("spree_preferences"."key" = 'spree/print_invoice_setting/store_pdf' AND "spree_preferences"."id" != 21) LIMIT 1
2015-09-01T15:20:12.834046+00:00 app[web.1]: App 111 stdout:    (0.6ms)  BEGIN
2015-09-01T15:20:13.143105+00:00 app[web.1]: App 111 stdout:   Spree::Store Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "spree_stores".* FROM "spree_stores" WHERE "spree_stores"."default" = 't'  ORDER BY "spree_stores"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
2015-09-01T15:20:15.865156+00:00 app[web.1]: App 111 stdout:
2015-09-01T15:20:16.085186+00:00 app[web.1]: [ 2015-09-01 15:20:16.0850 70/7f6e13fff700 age/Cor/Req/CheckoutSession.cpp:252 ]: [Client 2-1] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 12c29fd9. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060822+00:00 app[web.1]: [ 2015-09-01 15:20:16.0606 70/7f6e2b755700 App/Implementation.cpp:303 ]: Could not spawn process for application /app: An error occured while starting up the preloader.
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060827+00:00 app[web.1]:   Error ID: 12c29fd9
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060837+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/spree-heroku-3a3aa2165202/app/models/taxon_decorator.rb:1:in `class_eval'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060840+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060834+00:00 app[web.1]:   Message from application: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060833+00:00 app[web.1]:   Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-5vvjaw.html
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060841+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060843+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060836+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/spree-heroku-3a3aa2165202/app/models/taxon_decorator.rb:18:in `block in <top (required)>'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060838+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/spree-heroku-3a3aa2165202/app/models/taxon_decorator.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060846+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/spree-heroku-3a3aa2165202/lib/spree_heroku/engine.rb:14:in `block in activate'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060844+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060847+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/spree-heroku-3a3aa2165202/lib/spree_heroku/engine.rb:13:in `glob'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060849+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:446:in `instance_exec'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060850+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:446:in `block in make_lambda'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060851+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:192:in `c
all'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060856+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `block in call'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060857+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `each'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060854+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:192:in `block in simple'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060855+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060842+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060848+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/spree-heroku-3a3aa2165202/lib/spree_heroku/engine.rb:13:in `activate'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060871+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:50:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060877+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060865+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060858+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060861+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060862+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060866+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:83:in `prepare!'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060869+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:55:in `prepare!'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060893+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.112000+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=zeitschild-staging.herokuapp.com request_id=b9a89bca-a107-4e2c-a1aa-3a73f591224a fwd="80.147.111.194" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8965ms status=500 bytes=3358
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060874+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060891+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060896+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060901+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060939+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060904+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060907+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060942+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060940+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060910+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060899+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060925+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060949+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060941+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060964+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060945+00:00 app[web.1]:   config.ru:3:in `require'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060946+00:00 app[web.1]:   config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060965+00:00 app[web.1]:   config.ru:1:in `new'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060969+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.11/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:107:in `eval'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060979+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.11/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060976+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.11/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060973+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.11/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:153:in `<module:App>'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060982+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060966+00:00 app[web.1]:   config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060970+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.11/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:107:in `preload_app'
2015-09-01T15:20:16.060984+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-09-01T15:20:16.083508+00:00 app[web.1]: [ 2015-09-01 15:20:16.0833 70/7f6e290aa700 age/Cor/Req/CheckoutSession.cpp:252 ]: [Client 1-1] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 12c29fd9. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
2015-09-01T15:20:16.578359+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=zeitschild-staging.herokuapp.com request_id=b2ed9425-33b1-4c25-a1c5-70cf3d567e2c fwd="80.147.111.194" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=231
2015-09-01T15:27:06.385229+00:00 app[web.1]: App 131 stdout:
2015-09-01T15:27:11.186452+00:00 app[web.1]: App 131 stdout:   Spree::Preference Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "spree_preferences".* FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE "spree_preferences"."key" = $1  ORDER BY "spree_preferences"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["key", "spree/app_configuration/logo"]]
2015-09-01T15:27:11.206128+00:00 app[web.1]: App 131 stdout:   Spree::Preference Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE ("spree_preferences"."key" = 'spree/app_configuration/logo' AND "spree_preferences"."id" != 7) LIMIT 1
2015-09-01T15:27:11.209187+00:00 app[web.1]: App 131 stdout:   Spree::Preference Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "spree_preferences".* FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE "spree_preferences"."key" = $1  ORDER BY "spree_preferences"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["key", "spree/app_configuration/allow_guest_checkout"]]
2015-09-01T15:27:11.211332+00:00 app[web.1]: App 131 stdout:   Spree::Preference Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE ("spree_preferences"."key" = 'spree/app_configuration/allow_guest_checkout' AND "spree_preferences"."id" != 19) LIMIT 1
2015-09-01T15:27:11.218263+00:00 app[web.1]: App 131 stdout:   Spree::Preference Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "spree_preferences".* FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE "spree_preferences"."key" = $1  ORDER BY "spree_preferences"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["key", "spree/print_invoice_setting/storage_path"]]
2015-09-01T15:27:11.299453+00:00 app[web.1]: App 131 stdout:   Spree::Store Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "spree_stores".* FROM "spree_stores" WHERE "spree_stores"."default" = 't'  ORDER BY "spree_stores"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
2015-09-01T15:27:11.213749+00:00 app[web.1]: App 131 stdout:   Spree::Preference Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "spree_preferences".* FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE "spree_preferences"."key" = $1  ORDER BY "spree_preferences"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["key", "spree/print_invoice_setting/store_pdf"]]
2015-09-01T15:27:11.215793+00:00 app[web.1]: App 131 stdout:   Spree::Preference Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE ("spree_preferences"."key" = 'spree/print_invoice_setting/store_pdf' AND "spree_preferences"."id" != 21) LIMIT 1
2015-09-01T15:27:11.220471+00:00 app[web.1]: App 131 stdout:   Spree::Preference Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "spree_preferences" WHERE ("spree_preferences"."key" = 'spree/print_invoice_setting/storage_path' AND "spree_preferences"."id" != 22) LIMIT 1
2015-09-01T15:27:11.195785+00:00 app[web.1]: App 131 stdout:    (0.5ms)  BEGIN
2015-09-01T15:27:11.207636+00:00 app[web.1]: App 131 stdout:    (0.5ms)  COMMIT
2015-09-01T15:27:11.210253+00:00 app[web.1]: App 131 stdout:    (0.4ms)  BEGIN
2015-09-01T15:27:11.212447+00:00 app[web.1]: App 131 stdout:    (0.5ms)  COMMIT
2015-09-01T15:27:11.214728+00:00 app[web.1]: App 131 stdout:    (0.4ms)  BEGIN
2015-09-01T15:27:11.216889+00:00 app[web.1]: App 131 stdout:    (0.4ms)  COMMIT
2015-09-01T15:27:11.219351+00:00 app[web.1]: App 131 stdout:    (0.4ms)  BEGIN
2015-09-01T15:27:11.221647+00:00 app[web.1]: App 131 stdout:    (0.4ms)  COMMIT
2015-09-01T15:27:13.745940+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.745943+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.745944+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.745948+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.745818+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/spree-heroku-3a3aa2165202/app/models/taxon_decorator.rb:18:in `block in <top (required)>'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.745924+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.745921+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/spree-heroku-3a3aa2165202/app/models/taxon_decorator.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.745809+00:00 app[web.1]:   Error ID: 89ea2594
2015-09-01T15:27:13.745920+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/spree-heroku-3a3aa2165202/app/models/taxon_decorator.rb:1:in `class_eval'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.745816+00:00 app[web.1]:   Message from application: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
2015-09-01T15:27:13.745806+00:00 app[web.1]: [ 2015-09-01 15:27:13.7456 70/7f6e2b755700 App/Implementation.cpp:303 ]: Could not spawn process for application /app: An error occured while starting up the preloader.
2015-09-01T15:27:13.745815+00:00 app[web.1]:   Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-Jkphn8.html
2015-09-01T15:27:13.745950+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/spree-heroku-3a3aa2165202/lib/spree_heroku/engine.rb:14:in `block in activate'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.745956+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/spree-heroku-3a3aa2165202/lib/spree_heroku/engine.rb:13:in `activate'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.745959+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:446:in `instance_exec'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.745962+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:446:in `block in make_lambda'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.745968+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:192:in `block in simple'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.745973+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `block in call'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.745970+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.745976+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `each'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.745979+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.745953+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/spree-heroku-3a3aa2165202/lib/spree_heroku/engine.rb:13:in `glob'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.745965+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:192:in `call'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.745982+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746003+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746005+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746012+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:50:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746013+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746011+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:55:in `prepare!'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746016+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746021+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746024+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746017+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746006+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:83:in `prepare!'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746020+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746027+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746033+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746036+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746030+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746038+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746044+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746064+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746047+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746068+00:00 app[web.1]:   config.ru:3:in `require'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746071+00:00 app[web.1]:   config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746041+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2015-09-01T15:27
:13.746074+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746077+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746080+00:00 app[web.1]:   config.ru:1:in `new'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746082+00:00 app[web.1]:   config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746085+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.11/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:107:in `eval'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746088+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.11/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:107:in `preload_app'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746091+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.11/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:153:in `<module:App>'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746094+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.11/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746111+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.11/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746113+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-09-01T15:27:13.746114+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-09-01T15:27:13.757210+00:00 app[web.1]: [ 2015-09-01 15:27:13.7571 70/7f6e12f7d700 age/Cor/Req/CheckoutSession.cpp:252 ]: [Client 3-1] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 89ea2594. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
2015-09-01T15:27:13.560577+00:00 app[web.1]: App 131 stdout:
2015-09-01T15:27:13.783424+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=zeitschild-staging.herokuapp.com request_id=d164e132-09b5-43c3-9ae0-04e98a642b99 fwd="80.147.111.194" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7438ms status=500 bytes=3358
2015-09-01T15:27:14.208860+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=zeitschild-staging.herokuapp.com request_id=2022ff75-79f0-47a7-8e17-d2b3fd0e5437 fwd="80.147.111.194" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=231
```

Hope anybody can help me!

Comment: Does you App runs fine locally in `staging` environment ? Try starting you staging server locally before trying it on Heroku. You do not need to change `database.yml` as it is ignored by heroku.

Comment: Nope! But I get another error message..

/Users/mmintel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@zeitschild/bundler/gems/spree-heroku-3a3aa2165202/app/models/image_decorator.rb:18:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: and the line in that file says ":url => (S3_CONFIG['url'] || ":s3_path_url")"

though also for production I've only set up this in my production.rb and the right environment variables on heroku

config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_host_name => 's3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com',
    :s3_credentials => {
        :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET'],
        :access_key_id => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],
        :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET']
      }
  }

Answer (score 0):

I am so stupid! Forgot to add staging settings in my secrets.yml!